Call .NET Core API From Visual Basic 6 Client - POST
I am trying to call an API written in .Net Core from a Visual Basic 6 program.
this works
    Dim theURL As String
    Dim theHTTP As Object
    Dim theResponse As String

        theURL = "https://somewhere"
        Set theHTTP = CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP.6.0")
        theHTTP.Open "GET", theURL, False
        theHTTP.Send 
        theResponse = theHTTP.ResponseText

the GET is implemented only to test the deployment of the API - it's the POST which does the actual work
this returns a 415 error code
    Dim theURL As String
    Dim theHTTP As Object
    Dim theBody As String
    Dim theResponse As String

        theURL = "https://somewhere"
        theBody = "{keyvault: { URI: 'bla bla bla',  secretname: 'the user id'}}"
        Set theHTTP = CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP.6.0")
        theHTTP.Open "POST", theURL, False
        theHTTP.setRequestHeader "ContentType", "application/json"
        theHTTP.Send theBody
        theResponse = theHTTP.ResponseText

what am I missing?  adding an Accept request header doesn't fix it

theURL is https://myAPI.corp.inc/ etc
the URI is the key vault URI
    Dim thePassword As String
    Dim theUserID As String
    Dim theURL As String
    Dim theURI As String
    Dim theHTTP As Object
' MSXML2.XMLHTTP
    Dim theBody As String
    Dim theResponse As String
        theURL = txtURL.Text
        theURI = txtURI.Text
        theUserID = txtUserID.Text
        theBody = "{ " & """keyvault""" & ": { " & """URI""" & ": """ & theURI & """," _
            & """secretname""" & ": """ & theUserID & """} }"
        Set theHTTP = CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP.6.0")
        theHTTP.Open "POST", theURL, False
        theHTTP.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/json"
        txtLog.Text = theBody
        theHTTP.Send theBody
        theResponse = theHTTP.ResponseText
        txtPassword.Text = theResponse
        Set theHTTP = Nothing

theBody needed a lot more apostrophes apparantly
